# doesnt work TO insert query using mysqli stmt before mail() in a form contact

Tags: php, email, mysqli, sql-insert

I can't add queries in a database before function mail().
So I made a php form contact message with
1. to insert the message in  a mysql db - does not work(It does not insert a query in the column `contactmesaj` - and is not showing me any error...)
2. to send to my address a mail with the message of the user - works

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code......

```
<?php session_start();  ?>
<?php
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

if(isset($_POST['mesajContact'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mesaj = $_POST['message'];
    $telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
    $oferta = $_POST['oferta'];
    $subiect ='pachet: '.$oferta;

    require "connectare_db.php";//open DB
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO contactmesaj (nume, mail, mesaj, telefon, oferta) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $nume, $email, $mesaj, $telefon, $oferta);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $_SESSION["contactMesaj"]="Succes";//pentru mesaj succes adaugare
    } else{
        $_SESSION["contactMesaj"]="Failed";
    }
    $stmt->free_result();       
    $stmt->close();
    $con->close();

    $to = 'contact@realizare-site-ieftin.ro, stefan.jucatoru@gmail.com';
    $message = 'NUME: '.$name.'<BR> MAIL: '.$email.'<BR>TELEFON: '.$telefon.'<BR>Continut MESAJ: '.$mesaj;
    $headers = 'From: '.$email.'' . "\r\n";

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
        mail($to, $oferta, $message, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
    }

    //echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=../contact.php">';
else{
    echo "Invalid Email, please provide an correct email.";
    //header("location: ../contact.php"); 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to your error display settings as well to get mysqli errors shouted at you

Comment: Thank you, I found the error using the code above